# Facebook registration's password field returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have trouble including a password field for facebook registration plugin, below is the code which works:

`<fb:registration fields="name,email" redirect_uri="redirect_uri_here" />`

This however, is the code which returns 500 Internal Server Error:

`<fb:registration fields="name,password,email" redirect_uri="redirect_uri_here" />`

Only change is the included password field.

Headers sent: http://pastebin.com/qvng3B8P

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing same issue , 
The trick is use the password field as a custom field , e.g below

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
             client_id=XXX&
             redirect_uri=http://www.XXX&fields=[
 {'name':'name'},
 {'name':'email'},
  {'name':'pass',      'description':'Website XXX Password',             'type':'text'}

]" scrolling="auto"
        frameborder="no"
        style="border:none"
        allowTransparency="true"
        width="100%"
        height="310px">
</iframe>
```

ALSO use the xfmbl version so you can use field verification and force user to type in password